# In WiX, how would you create a dialog to choose the name of a subfolder of the main application directory?

Tags: wix, dialog, directory

I am developing an [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) installer by using [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX).

The main program installs to [APPLICATIONFOLDER]. I use the `InstallDirDlg` to set the directory of this without any issues.

I'd like to display a custom dialogue based on the `InstallDirDlg` to specify a directory to install a particular component. I'd like to set the default directory to [APPLICATIONFOLDER]\Resources.  However when I run the installer, I get an error, code 2343.

I think this may be a problem with displaying a second level folder in the dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at how this is done in the WixUI FeatureTree UI example. In particular, look at the [CustomizeDlg](http://www.wixwiki.com/index.php?title=CustomizeDlg).

The error 2343 means "Specified path is empty.", so you have probably set a property incorrectly. Looking at the [log files generated by your installer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300) may also help.